# Rescuperar dados de uma Lista de objetos no HTML

Tags: c#, html, .net, asp.net-core, nav-bar

Olá, eu tenho uma Lista de objetos que está sendo criada em um método OnGet e eu preciso pegar todos os dados dela para colocar na minha página html, como eu consigo recuperar estes dados?

```
List<string> MenuPrincipal = new List<string>();
int i = 1;
while (result.vfp.row[i].men == "_MSYSMENU")
{
    MenuPrincipal.Add(result.vfp.row[i].des);
    i++;
}
```

Ele tem valores de string, ja verifiquei isso... como por exemplo, o `MenuPrincipal[0]`, tem valor `exemplo`. E o `MenuPrincipal[1]`, tem valor `exemplo2`.

Enfim, eu preciso fazer com que o `exemplo`, seja um item do meu menu na barra de navegação e o `exemplo2`, seja outro item desta mesma barra, e deles saírão um submenu que será preenchido da mesma forma, porém mais a frente.

Me ajudem por favor, obrigado.

Comment: Tens de detalhar mais o que pretendes. Pretendes transformar cada item dessa List<string> numa opção de menu em html?

Comment: Exatamente @iamdlm

Answer (score 0):

Para converter uma lista de string para uma lista em HTML podes utilizar o seguinte método (sem recursividade):

```
private void BuildList(List<string> menu)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("<ul>");
    foreach (string item in menu)
    {
        sb.Append("<li>" + item + "</li>");                
    }
    sb.Append("</ul>");
}
```